# QR Code Scanning not working

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, qr-code, swift4

So I have just taken over an iOS project as their first in-house dev, where previously this app had been developed by an agency.

One of the features of the app is that it needs to scan QR codes—by the look of the code the previous developers have followed [this](https://www.appcoda.com/qr-code-reader-swift/) tutorial on AppCoda to implement the QR scan. Everything looks fine and I can't see anything wrong with the code yet it isn't working.

I also downloaded the completed tutorial project and that worked when I tried the QR scan. I also tried copying and pasting every single line so that it was identical to the working tutorial yet no luck.

I'm tearing my hair out trying to figure out why it isn't working.

Any help is much appreciated!

```
enum ScanState : Int {
  case newDevice = 1
  case resetDevice = 2
  case replaceDevice = 3
}

class QRScannerViewController: BaseViewController,AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate {
  @IBOutlet var scanZoneView: UIView!
  @IBOutlet var scannerVIew: UIView!
  @IBOutlet var scanInfoLabel: UILabel!

  var capturedQR: String? = nil
  var captureSession:AVCaptureSession?
  var videoPreviewLayer:AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer?
  var qrCodeFrameView:UIView?
  let supportedBarCodes = [AVMetadataObject.ObjectType.qr, AVMetadataObject.ObjectType.code128, AVMetadataObject.ObjectType.code39, AVMetadataObject.ObjectType.code93, AVMetadataObject.ObjectType.upce, AVMetadataObject.ObjectType.pdf417, AVMetadataObject.ObjectType.ean13, AVMetadataObject.ObjectType.aztec]
  var type = "leg scan"


  var device:Device?
  var state:ScanState = .newDevice

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    scanInfoLabel.text = "Scan your existing\nleg QR code"

    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.dark()

    //self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: .Plain, target: nil, action: nil)
  }

  override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: true)
  }

  override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    #if NOHARDWARE
      moveToNextViewController()
    #else
      initiateCapture()
    #endif
  }

  func initiateCapture() {
    let captureDevice = AVCaptureDevice.default(for: AVMediaType.video)
    // Get an instance of the AVCaptureDeviceInput class using the previous device object.
    var error:NSError?
    let input: AnyObject!
    do {
      input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevice!) as AVCaptureDeviceInput
    } catch let error1 as NSError {
      error = error1
      input = nil
    } catch _ {
      input = nil
    }

    if (error != nil) {
      // If any error occurs, simply log the description of it and don't continue any more.
      print("\(error?.localizedDescription)")
      return
    }
    // Initialize the captureSession object.
    captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
    // Set the input device on the capture session.
    captureSession?.addInput(input as! AVCaptureInput)

    // Initialize a AVCaptureMetadataOutput object and set it as the output device to the capture session.
    let captureMetadataOutput = AVCaptureMetadataOutput()
    captureSession?.addOutput(captureMetadataOutput)

    // Set delegate and use the default dispatch queue to execute the call back
    captureMetadataOutput.setMetadataObjectsDelegate(self, queue: DispatchQueue.main)
    captureMetadataOutput.metadataObjectTypes = supportedBarCodes

    // Initialize the video preview layer and add it as a sublayer to the viewPreview view's layer.
    videoPreviewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession!)
    videoPreviewLayer?.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill
    videoPreviewLayer?.frame = scannerVIew.layer.bounds
    scannerVIew.layer.addSublayer(videoPreviewLayer!)

    // Start video capture.
    captureSession?.startRunning()


    // Initialize QR Code Frame to highlight the QR code
    qrCodeFrameView = UIView()
    qrCodeFrameView?.layer.borderColor = UIColor.green.cgColor
    qrCodeFrameView?.layer.borderWidth = 2
    scannerVIew.addSubview(qrCodeFrameView!)
    scannerVIew.bringSubview(toFront: qrCodeFrameView!)
    //qrCapturedLabel.text = "No QR code is detected"

  }

  override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
  }

  func metadataOutput(captureOutput: AVCaptureMetadataOutput, didOutput metadataObjects: [AVMetadataObject], from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {

    // Check if the metadataObjects array is not nil and it contains at least one object.
    if metadataObjects == nil || metadataObjects.count == 0 {
      qrCodeFrameView?.frame = CGRect.zero

      return
    }

    // Get the metadata object.
    let metadataObj = metadataObjects[0] as! AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject

    // Here we use filter method to check if the type of metadataObj is supported
    // Instead of hardcoding the AVMetadataObjectTypeQRCode, we check if the type
    // can be found in the array of supported bar codes.
    if supportedBarCodes.filter({ $0 == metadataObj.type }).count > 0 {
      // If the found metadata is equal to the QR code metadata then update the status label's text and set the bounds
      let barCodeObject = videoPreviewLayer?.transformedMetadataObject(for: metadataObj as AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject) as! AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject

      let intersectionRect = barCodeObject.bounds.intersection(self.scanZoneView.frame)

      if !intersectionRect.isNull &&
        (intersectionRect.size.width * intersectionRect.size.height) > self.scanZoneView.bounds.width * self.scanZoneView.bounds.height / 7 {

        qrCodeFrameView?.frame = barCodeObject.bounds

        if process(metadataObj.stringValue!) {
          captureSession?.stopRunning()
        }
      }
    }
  }

  @IBAction func didTapCancel(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
  }
}

extension QRScannerViewController {


  func process(_ scanText : String) -> Bool {

    var legCode : String

    let codeComponents = scanText.components(separatedBy: ";")
    if codeComponents.count > 0 {
      legCode = codeComponents[0]
    } else {
      // Invalid number of parameters seperated by a ;
      return false
    }

    // TODO Validate the LEG to LEG-XXXXX
    if legCode.hasPrefix("LEG-") {
      let delta: Int64 = 1 * Int64(NSEC_PER_SEC)
      let time = DispatchTime.now() + Double(delta) / Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)

      DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: time, execute: {

        switch self.state {

        case .resetDevice:

          let realm = try! Realm()
          let deviceList = realm.objects(Device.self)
          let lc = legCode

          self.device = deviceList.filter("legCode = %@", lc).first

          if self.device == nil {

            // TODO Error message: Device not associated with LEG
            let vc = ErrorViewController.createErrorViewController(.DeviceNotFound)
            self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
            return
          }

          self.moveToNextViewController()

        default:
          self.presentingViewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }

      });

      return true
    }

    return false
  }

  func moveToNextViewController() {
    let inspectionStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Impact", bundle: nil)

    if let resetVC = inspectionStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: ImpactDetectionViewController.storyboardID) as? ImpactDetectionViewController {
      resetVC.device = device
      // TODO Pass the impact type across too when the G2 API is set
      self.navigationController?.pushViewController(resetVC, animated: false)
    }
  }

  @IBAction func cancelToVC(_ segue: UIStoryboardSegue) { }

}
```

**EDIT**

By not working I mean the delegate for `AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate` is never being called so it never seems to be detecting a QR code. In the AppCoda tutorial it overlays a green square where it detects the QR code but this never happens when I put that code into this app.

The camera is actually running but QR codes are never deteced.

Comment: I think it's okay to share a library if I post it as a comment, I've been using this pod for easy life, just wanna suggest: https://github.com/yannickl/QRCodeReader.swift

Comment: Thanks Glenn, I did look into that but when I installed the pod there were like 11 errors coming from the framework so I decided it would just be easier to get this implementation working

Comment: Can you give us some more details? What happens when you run this code? Is camera running? Can you able to see the camera view frames? Did you try to check with breakpoint at`didOutput metadataObject` ?

Comment: BTW, what do you mean by `Not Working`? It would be better if you could give some more info.

Comment: Check this out: https://cocoapods.org/?q=lang%3Aswift%20QRCOde%20reader

Comment: Apologies, I will edit and provide more detail

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Turns out the answer was deceptively (and annoyingly) simple! Of course in Swift 4 the delegates have been renamed slightly. To fix all I had to was change

```
  func metadataOutput(captureOutput: AVCaptureMetadataOutput, didOutput metadataObjects: [AVMetadataObject], from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {
```

to

```
  func metadataOutput(_ output: AVCaptureMetadataOutput, didOutput metadataObjects: [AVMetadataObject], from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {
```

Comment: Thanks a lot bro ! you saved me lots of time :D

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer!

Answer (score -1):

You're not connecting your class to `AVCaptureMetadataOutput`'s delegate, that's why the `AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate` functions are not being invoked. More info: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturemetadataoutputobjectsdelegate

Try this:

```
// Initialize a AVCaptureMetadataOutput object and set it as the output device to the capture session.
    let captureMetadataOutput = AVCaptureMetadataOutput()
    captureMetadataOutput.metadataObjectsDelegate = self // assign self to the delegate.
    captureSession?.addOutput(captureMetadataOutput)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer—it seems to have made some progress. I moved around the lines of code and got a fatal error saying I was passing some unsupported types in `captureMetadataOutput.metadataObjectTypes` and to use `availableMetadataObjectTypes` instead. I did that but now `metadataObjectTypes` array is empty.